# tbl_QcPhaseWise is not part of the model for the current context

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework, .net-4.8

I am getting error in `Release` pipeline of Azure Devops however it is working perfectly fine the `Debug` pipeline.

I compared both the VSBuild logs and I found that in Debug it was

```
ValidateSolutionConfiguration:
  Building solution configuration "Debug|Any CPU".
Project "D:\a\1\s\Lab-So.sln" (1) is building "D:\a\1\s\Lab_So_Web\Lab_So_Web.csproj" (2) on node 1 (default targets).
EntityDeployNonEmbeddedResources:
Skipping target "EntityDeployNonEmbeddedResources" because it has no outputs.
EntityDeployEmbeddedResources:
  Processing 1 EDMX files.
  Starting to process input file 'Models\LabSoModel.edmx'.
  Finished processing input file 'Models\LabSoModel.edmx'.
  Finished processing 1 EDMX files.
```

The `.edmx` file is getting processed but for Release we got below logs

```
ValidateSolutionConfiguration:
  Building solution configuration "Release|Any CPU".
Project "D:\a\1\s\Lab-So.sln" (1) is building "D:\a\1\s\Lab_So_Web\Lab_So_Web.csproj" (2) on node 1 (default targets).
EntityDeployNonEmbeddedResources:
Skipping target "EntityDeployNonEmbeddedResources" because it has no outputs.
EntityDeployEmbeddedResources:
Skipping target "EntityDeployEmbeddedResources" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
TypeScriptDeleteOutputFromOtherConfigs:
  Deleting file "obj\Debug\Tsc.out".
```

The .edmx file is not getting processed.

I have added this table in the .csproj as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make changes in the csproj file. This way. you can mention which all files you want to include while building the project.

```
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
<DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
***<DebugType>full</DebugType>***
<Optimize>true</Optimize>
<OutputPath>bin\</OutputPath>
<DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
<ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
<WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
```